# No image from graphics card but image from onboard video

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, display, graphics

I have an HD 5970 running on a P8Z68-v LE motherboard and I have no image comming out of the graphic card.

- When I plug my screen on my motherboard, I see the bios and the
  OS.
- When I plug my screen on the graphic card, I don't see anything.
- I know that the graphic card works because I have tested it on
  another computer.
- I know the motherboard works because I tested it with another graphic
  card and it worked.
- I know that the graphic card works with the computer because I have
  another computer with a P8Z68-LE and an HD 5970.
- I know it is not an OS issue because I should atleast be able to see the bios. I have tried unplugging my HDDs so that the OS dont interfere with anything.
- Using a 1000W power supply

Using another HD5970 on the computer works. So this is a problem with my HD5970, but why is the graphic card working on my other computer?

Comment: Is your powersupply delivering enough power to the GPU?

Comment: @kobaltz The power supply on my 3 machines is the same. So yes, it should. It is a 1000W power supply

Comment: You won't necessarily see the bios, I have had a similar setup where the secondary card is not initialised until fairly late if the default card is set to be the integrated.  Look in the bios for a Integrated Graphics / PCI graphics priority or primary setting.

Comment: +1 for troubleshooting first, and telling us. :)

Comment: *I know the motherboard works because I tested it with another graphic card and it worked.* Does the other graphics card use the same 6(+2) pin power connector?

Comment: You can also change the BIOS to enable PCI cards as your primary. I'm using the same motherboard as you with an ATI 6970 and Integrated Graphics. 3 monitors on the ATI card and 1 monitor on the integrated.

Comment: @kobaltz & Paul : I am not familiar with this type of settings, so I took a picture of my settings: http://bayimg.com/OALpMAadG. Also, those are the same settings that are on my other computer. (The computer with the same graphics gard and the same computer. Remember that I can see he bios on this computer.)

Comment: @Dennis: The other graphic card is using a 6pin connector.
The 5970 is using a 6 pin & 6+2pin
When I unplug any of the additional connectors(even the 2pin), a red light turns on. I think that this prooves that power is going trough?

Comment: EDIT: @kobaltz & Paul : I am not familiar with this type of settings, so I took a picture of my settings: bayimg.com/OALpMAadG. Also, those are the same settings that are on my other computer. (The computer with the same graphics gard and the same __MOTHERBOARD__. Remember that I can see he bios on this computer.)

Comment: @ReAzem: Since you have another computer with the same graphics card, you could try that one. Or a multimeter, if you have one. It's a long shot, but I can't think of anything else...

Comment: @Dennis: This just worked. Thank you Everyone.
But... What does this mean? Why is the graphics card working on the other computer?

Comment: This does not explain why one of my HD5970 works on only one motherboard o.O

Comment: @ReAzem re-test the card in the computer that it worked in, but don't just see if it boots up.  Make sure it works fine (run a 3D application, make sure there's no tearing, overheating, etc...).  I have a Z68-based chipset, and from that picture, your BIOS settings look fine.  Also, most power supplies have to different +12V rails.  Make sure the 6-pin and 6+2-pin connectors come from *different 12V rails* (they each have their own current rating, it's possible that you are drawing too much on a single rail).

Comment: If you're running Windows, boot into [Safe Mode](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chsafe.htm) and set the screen resolution for the graphics card down to the lowest (640x480), then boot back into normal mode and try increasing the resolution. It may be that the default resolution is set too high for the video to display.

Comment: this aint the answer. but why don't you swap the 2 5970s between your 2 machines. try if that works...

Comment: Be sure you enable your BIOS display settings to use the PCI-E graphics card, not the on-board video.

Answer (score 1):

Does your motherboard have a second PCI-E slot? If so try that, could be a dead slot. Also check your bios and see if you can find a default Video output option, like set it to PCI-E instead of onboard, You can also try to disable the onboard video and see if that works. Its not that card at all, since it works in another system. ITs got to be a setting on the motherboard somewhere, You can also try to unplug the power from the computer, and then take the cmos battery out for a min or so, then put it back and plug the PC back in. It will reset the bios.

Also try a different Powersupply, maybe the plugs that go into the Video card have died.

Answer (score 1):

It's got a be a super simple solution judging by all the other testing you've done.

I'd make sure you first double check to make sure you meet the minimum system requirements of card. 30+ AMPS on 12+ rail, total psu wattage, both pci-e power connections are in, and that the card is the PRIMARY PCI-Ex16 slot.

Make sure bios is set to load pci graphics above ONBOARD. Make sure when you change the video cable from onboard to the card you restart the computer. Most boards don't hotswap from onboard to discrete. System needs to reboot to show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You say: Using another HD5970 on the computer works

I would check board revisions and firmware revisions on the cards